# Являются ли нежелательной рекламой ссылки на книги в интернет-магазинах? Чем их можно заменить?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, ссылки, спам, учебные-материалы

Часто приходится видеть в ответах ссылки на интернет-магазины, в особенности, `ozon.ru`. Примеры:

- [.NET профессионал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414595/199934) — в конце ответа 4 ссылки на OZON,
- [Материал для ios разработки на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/217377/199934) — здесь так в каждом из четырёх ответов ссылка на этот интернет-магазин.

В итоге имеем продвижение одного интернет-магазина в ущерб другим. Не знаю, как сообществу, а мне кажется, что Stack Overflow на русском не предназначен для рекламы `ozon.ru`. Дополнительные связанные меж собой аргументы не в пользу сложившейся практики:

- Цена в интернет-магазине, ссылка на который приведена в сообщении, может быть выше, нежели у конкурентов. А стоимость — фактически главный фактор, почему отдаётся предпочтение тому или иному магазину.
- Нужные книги могут временно отсутствовать в продаже.
- Неудобство для пользователей. Они всё равно будут искать варианты подешевле, а если книга отсутуствует — где она в наличии.

Предлагаю вместо ссылок на отдельные интернет-магазины использовать ссылки на поисковые системы по ним, что устраняет вышеперечисленные проблемы. Из вариантов (`Knigoed.info`, `bookzi.ru`) наиболее предпочтительным для меня представляется поисковик [`Findbook.ru`](http://Findbook.ru), существующий аж с [2000 года](http://web.archive.org/web/20001121020800/http://www.findbook.ru/), [как он работает](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?page=SearchHowTo).

Пример [поисковой выдачи](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=978-5-8459-1785-0&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0):

[image: Пример поисковой выдачи Findbook.ru]

Итого, предложение состоит в следующем:

- Не рекомендовать, а лучше запретить правилами ссылки в сообщениях на отдельные интернет-магазины;
- Дать добро замене ссылок на интернет-магазины ссылками на поисковые системы по ним.

Comment: "Предлагаю вместо ссылок на отдельные интернет-магазины использовать ссылки на поисковые системы по ним" - те же яйца, вид сбоку - "в итоге имеем продвижение одних _поисковых систем_ в ущерб другим"

Comment: @Kromster, так и знал, что будет произнесено нечто подобное. / **1)** в итоге имеем продвижение одних *поисковых систем* в ущерб другим" — нигде в посте не написано, что стоит предпочитать одну поисковую систему другим. Вывел в примере FindBook, потому что он  *функционально* лучше конкурентов, что отнюдь не запрещает использовать другие поисковые системы. / **2)** Аналогия не совсем корректна по ключевому признаку. Интернет-магазины финансово заинтересованы в продвижении своих услуг, чего нельзя сказать о поисковых системах по ним. Ранжирование, как видно на примере, ведётся по цене. Спасибо.

Comment: *нигде в посте не написано, что стоит предпочитать одну поисковую систему другим.* - в итоге каждый будет писать ссылки тех *поисковых систем* которые ему нравятся, что я считаю заменой шила на мыло. единственный вариант унифицировать, но как я сказал мне было бы лень переносить/поддерживать в актуальном состоянии такой перечень книг

Comment: > единственный вариант унифицировать — Зачем? Что плохого в ссылках на различные поисковые системы? Спасибо.

Comment: вот и я не пойму зачем менять одни ссылки на другие ссылки, альтернатива, ссылка на книгу на сайте издательства.

Comment: > вот и я не пойму зачем менять одни ссылки на другие ссылки — Опять же расписано в посте. // > альтернатива, ссылка на книгу на сайте издательства. — Считаю хорошей. Спасибо.

Comment: ни как не могу до вас донести, аргументы приведенные в посте я не считаю проблемой. у всех есть свои привычки, мне предложенная вами схема будет не удобной, мне проще в *поисковике* набрать название книги и дальше смотреть

Comment: @Bald, на ответы к основному аргументу: «ссылки на интернет-магазины — реклама коммерческих ресурсов» ответил здесь и в комментариях к Вашему ответу. // По поводу дополнительных аргументов: **1)** Мой вариант как раз предоставляет пользователям выбор, где смотреть описание книги и прочие выходные данные, **2)** Что Вам удобнее — понял, однако по-прежнему считаю, что специализированные поисковые системы в данном случае удобнее универсальных. Спасибо.

Comment: Складывается ощущение, что присутствует личная неприязнь именно к озону :-)

Comment: _1) Мой вариант как раз предоставляет пользователям выбор, где смотреть описание книги и прочие выходные данные,_ - ну вообще нет, вы предлагаете ссылку на какой-то **конкретный** малоизвестный сайт, возможно имеется ваша заинтересованность в этом.

Comment: *однако по-прежнему считаю, что специализированные поисковые системы в данном случае удобнее универсальных.* - на это я Вам уже написал что тогда как альтернатива ссылка на сайт издательства. поймите меня правильно ссылки на поисковые системы будут тем же самым что и ссылка на интернет магазин(ну да есть плюс ввиду отображения цен в различных источниках), разные пользователи будут указывать разные *поисковики*, Вашими же словами, а если указанной ссылке не будет того магазина где есть эта книга, или где она дешевле. что тогда?

Comment: > Складывается ощущение, что присутствует личная неприязнь именно к озону :-) — Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от предположения моих целей, давайте обсуждать аргументы. Спасибо.

Comment: > а если указанной ссылке не будет того магазина где есть эта книга.  — Сервисы вроде FindBook показывают ссылки на интернет-магазины, где книга есть. А как раз на Озоне или его альтернативах она может временно не оказаться в наличии. Спасибо.

Comment: > ну вообще нет, вы предлагаете ссылку на какой-то конкретный малоизвестный сайт, — прямое некорректное утверждение. Из поста: *Предлагаю вместо ссылок на отдельные интернет-магазины использовать ссылки на поисковые системы по ним*, *Дать добро замене ссылок на интернет-магазины ссылками на поисковые системы по ним.* — я не предлагал ссылаться именно на FindBook, а упомянул, что на основании сравнительных данных этот вариант выглядит лично для меня наиболее предпочтительным, а также упомянул альтернативы. Спасибо.

Comment: > малоизвестный сайт — **1)** Каким образом определяется «известность»? В Википедии он достаточно известен, с 2005 года используется как источник на странице [источников книг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3). / **2)** *Оффтоп*: пишу сейчас работу о поведенческих характеристиках программистов, как раз выделил раздел об их предвзятом отношении с малоизвестным ресурсам, предположив, что это признак класса в целом, а не отдельных конкретных программистов. Спасибо.

Comment: указывайте ник того кому пишите при помощи связки символа `@`НикПользователя, что бы пришла нотификация. Вы не поняли: на ваши аргументы что на озоне только озон, а вдруг её там нет, или где то она дешевле мой вопрос: *А если указанной ссылке не будет того магазина где есть эта книга, или где она дешевле. что тогда?* ведь тогда это будет не лучше чем сейчас

Comment: @СашаЧерных, предвзятое отношение к малоизвестным ресурсам вряд ли является характеристикой только программистов. Или "программисты" в данном случае это те, кто работает на компьютере? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ну, я и не утверждал, что признак *только* программистов.

Comment: это я к тому, что это не может быть признаком класса программистов, так как не зависит программист человек или нет

Comment: @Grundy, ОК, спасибо, дельное замечание.

Comment: Спам - массовая рассылка, а вопрос только про рекламу вроде бы.

Comment: @edem, согласен. Термин «спам» часто употребляется некорректно.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Не понимаю, откуда столько минусов. Каждый раз, когда я вижу массовые ссылки на Амазон, Озон и что там ещё на странице Stack Overflow, у меня возникает ощущение, что я куда-то не туда попал. Это правда Stack Overflow, а не проплаченный рекламный блок или вовсе проплаченная рекламная статья, маскирующаяся под нормальную?

Ну правда же — ссылка на Озон выглядит куда сомнительнее, чем ссылка на поисковик или агрегатор. А ссылка на сайт издательства была бы идеальна, по-моему.

Так или иначе, я считаю, что программисты — достаточно образованный народ, чтобы быть в состоянии заказать книжку своими силами, без помощи массовых ссылок на коммерческие сайты.

Comment: согласен про ссылку на сайт издательство, большинство ссылок ведут на *озон, амазон* и прочие интернет магазины только потому что при поиске ссылки на данные ресурсы в первых строках. и давать ссылки на них соответственно проще

Comment: «Эффект Дискорда» — стоило Вам ответить, как рейтинг вопроса вырос с -4 до нуля :) .

Comment: @СашаЧерных ещё заголовок был переформулирован. Первоначальный вариант слабо отражал суть вопроса.

Comment: Да, наплевать, реклама это магазина или нет. Думаю, большинство об этом не задумывается (и правильно делает) и просто дает первую же попавшуюся **подходящую** ссылку с целью наглядной демонстрации обложки, м.б. содержания и т.п. (чтобы вопрошающему, проще ее (книгу), было себе представить).

Comment: @avp: С другой стороны, любой из нас в состоянии загуглить по названию книги, и увидеть ту же обложку.

Comment: @VladD, может, а если книжка заинтересовала, то наверняка будет гуглить, чтобы  почитать ее прямо сейчас в электронном виде. Но с готовой ссылкой выглядит красивей.

Comment: @avp: Честнее было бы давать ссылку на торрент, но (1) она протухает, и (2) не в любой стране доступна. И разумеется (3) незаконно :(

Comment: @VladD, разумеется. Но если ничего не путаю, то тут как-то была борьба с такими пиратскими ссылками (вымарывали их или удаляли ответы с ними), поэтому и пишем ссылки на платный ресурс (кому надо, потом за полчасика найдет и пиратов).

Answer (score 11):

Cсылки на Amazon на основном Stack Overflow магическим образом [становятся реферальными](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links). Такая конвертация проводится [аж с 2009 года](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/).

Иначе говоря, коммерческая компания — владелец сайта Stack Overflow — извлекает выгоду из этих ссылок. Это правильно, на то она и коммерческая — сервера для наших вопросов и ответов поддерживает, а с остатков налоги платит. Всё честно.

Потому логично было бы чтобы и от переходов по ссылкам на Озон сайт получал что-то.

Answer (score 7):

На мой взгляд ссылка на книгу в каком то конкретном магазине может быть дана с целью получения более подробной информации по ней (по крайней мере я так делаю), а не в целях продвижения интернет магазина, а уж покупать книгу именно там или искать какой то другой вариант, и как искать это сугубо личное дело каждого, поэтому заставлять подстраиваться под себя мне кажется **слегка** избыточным.

---

как вариант можно было бы утвердить правила указания литературы, например:

*Наименование, ISBN, автор/соавторы, год издания издательство* но я бы предпочел не рекомендовать книгу таким образом в виду *природной лени*

Comment: **1)** Может, у проставляющих целей и нет, но фактически получается реклама, причём, источников, коммерчески заинтересованных в продвижении своей продукции. / **2)** Не совсем понял, почему «подстраиваться под себя». Спасибо.

Comment: как заметил @Kromster в вашем случае будет реклама *поисковых систем*, с чем я согласен, почему Вы решили что вариант предложенный вами удобнее?

Comment: > как заметил @Kromster в вашем случае будет реклама поисковых систем — О «рекламе» отписал в ответе Kromster. // > почему Вы решили что вариант предложенный вами удобнее? — Аргументы расписал в самом посте. Спасибо.